# MongoDB C# Iteration as enumerator

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a large collection of items with MongoDB (> 10m).

The code is in C# / .NET.

On occasion, I need to iterate through all the documents to prune data, do some other maintenance, etc.
also, in some cases, I need to be able to iterate through all documents but only get the Id of each document.

I want the documents to be presents as an IEnumerable for consumption by code which is used to process lists, etc.

I did the following:

```
    private static IAsyncCursor<MongoAlbum> GetCursor(Parameters...)
    {
        var F = MakeFilter(Parameters...);
        var Cursor = Mongo.Driver.FindAsync(F).Result;
        return Cursor;
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<string> IterateThroughAlbumIds(Parameters...)
    {
        using (var Cursor = GetCursor(Parameters...))
        {
            while (Cursor.MoveNextAsync().Result)
            {
                var Batch = Cursor.Current;
                foreach (var Document in Batch) yield return Document._id;
            }
        }
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<MongoAlbum> IterateThroughAlbums(Parameters...)
    {
        using (var Cursor = GetCursor(Parameters...))
        {
            while (Cursor.MoveNextAsync().Result)
            {
                var Batch = Cursor.Current;
                foreach (var Document in Batch) yield return Document;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to know two things:

- Is there a better way to make an async enumeration look like a .NET IEnumerable?
- During the enumeration, how can I tell the driver to only return the id of a document?

Comment: Async enumerable is still a problematic concept in .NET. Of course there's Rx and Ix (with Entity Framework async built on concepts from the latter), but there's no uniform support for either. Even more problematic is the async -> sync logical conversion (which is what you've got here). If you *must* have an `IEnumerable<T>` and call it synchronously and you want to do so with minimal coding effort, then what you're doing is *sort of OK* (although I'd use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` for blocking instead of `Result` for cleaner exception propagation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use ToEnumerable extension method for that and to get only the ID you need to use a projection.

The following code should work

```
public class MongoAlbum
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
IMongoClient client;
IMongoDatabase database;
IMongoCollection<MongoAlbum> collection;
client = new MongoClient("connection string");
database = client.GetDatabase("DB name");
collection = database.GetCollection<MongoAlbum>("collection name");
IEnumerable<string> albums = collection.Find(x => x.Id == "1")
                                       .Project(x => x.Id)
                                       .ToEnumerable<string>();
```

In this case it will be a List of strings since you will only get Ids results and in my MongoAlbum POCO i used a string.